# DNS: Setting White-Label NS with Amazon Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, routes, nameservers

We are hosting our domain DNS with Route 53 at Amazon since our domain provider doesn't provide a feature to create private name servers.

Now according to amazon, I have added the following Nameservers to my domain:

```
ns-1199.awsdns-21.org. 
ns-50.awsdns-06.com. 
ns-2026.awsdns-61.co.uk. 
ns-854.awsdns-42.net.
```

Then here is my setting:
[image]

Set the TTL low so it can quickly get set according to amazon's documentation. Note that its already been 24 hours.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name servers need to set be configured where your domain is registered, not within Route 53 hosted zones.

For example, if your domain is registered at GoDaddy, then you need to configure your domain at GoDaddy and input those name servers there.

If your domain is registered with AWS, then you need to configure your domain within Route 53, but not in the Hosted Zone. Instead, go to Registered Domains -> Your Domain -> Add or edit name servers.

And remove `ns1.etech.om` and `ns2.etech.om` from your `NS` record.